# iPhone : MapKit and displaying the current Map Scale

Tags: iphone, mapkit, scale

I need to display on the map a scale showing how far a inch / cm is for example.  This will need to change depending on the zoom level.

My theory is that if I know the length of the map, and the length of the graphic, If I know what the current scale of the map was I could just do some maths to work out the graphic indicator scale.

So is there a way to get the current zoom lvl in meters?  Is it linked to the span or something?

Comment: Sounds promising, what's your question?

Comment: I Think the second answer on this is correct with the 111 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270485/convert-span-value-into-meters-on-a-mapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom level is linked to the span - you first need to get the span of your map view, and then convert it into meters.

Comment: How do you convert the span to meters

Comment: Look at the doc for [MKCoordinateSpan](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009734-CH1-SW29). It gives you approximate values of what a degree is in kilometers. I can't give you a formula to convert longitude or latitude to meters from the top of my head though.